# Unexplained Comma On Tumblr Page

Tags: html, css, tumblr

[Screenshot of Problem Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdS76.jpg)

After slightly modifying a Tumblr theme, I have some to notice a stray comma on my "Ask a Question" and "Submit" page. This comma also seems to have a link anchored to it.

I've scanned through the code with my basic knowledge of HTML and CSS, but have come up empty. Is there an error in my code that is adding this stray comma, or is this something possibly out of my control?

Here's a link if it helps:
http://deathrebel224.tumblr.com/submit
The problem comma is located above the bold "Submit".

I appreciate any and all feedback

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/o8Bku9w35/reset.css" type="text/css" /> <style> body {
  color: {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
  background: {
    color: Background
  }
  url(http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/n5aky459v/fletch.png);
  font-family:Baskerville,
  "Times New Roman",
  Times,
  serif;
}
* html body {
  background: {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
  src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/xyTky45d1/league_gothic.eot');
  src: local('League Gothic Regular'), local('LeagueGothic'), url('http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/pheky45df/league_gothic.ttf') format('truetype');
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: {
    color: Links
  }
  ;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
hr {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
  margin: 22px auto;
  width: 243px;
}
#container {
  width: 772px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  padding-top: 24px;
}
#header ul {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
#header li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 12px;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", "Impact", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", "Impact", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
#header p {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 8px auto;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.09;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
}
#submit_asks {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}
.post-meta {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
}
.post-meta a {
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.post-content {
  margin: 22px 0;
}
.photo .photo-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.photo .photo-wrapper img {
  border: 8px solid {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(128,
  128,
  128,
  .35);
}
.photo.captioned .photo-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 22px 22px 0;
}
.photo .body {
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.photo .body p,
.photo .body blockquote {
  text-align: left;
}
.video .video-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 8px solid {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(128,
  128,
  128,
  .35);
}
.video.captioned .video-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 22px 22px 8px;
}
.video .body {
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.video .body p,
.video .body blockquote {
  text-align: left;
}
.quote .q-wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 22px;
  background: {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  padding:8px;
}
.quote q {
  border: 1px solid {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
  padding:7px 10px;
  display:block;
  font-family:"LeagueGothicRegular",
  "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",
  "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond",
  "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond",
  "Impact",
  sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  line-height:1.1;
  text-align:justify;
}
.quote p+p {
  text-indent: 1em;
}
.quote q.short {
  font-size: 42px;
}
.quote q.medium {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.quote q.long {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.quote .body {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text h2 {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 30px auto 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", "Impact", sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.text .body {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.audio-info {
  width: 207px;
  margin: 0 auto 22px;
}
.audio-info.hasart {
  width: 368px;
}
.audio-info-left img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(128, 128, 128, .35);
}
.audio-info-left {
  width: 139px;
  float: left;
  background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/j6Kky45bc/vinyl.png) no-repeat right center;
}
.audio-info-right {
  width: 207px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.audio-info-right div {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
.audio-trackname {
  font-style: italic;
}
.audio-album {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.audio-info-right .audio-player {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.audio .body {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.conversation h2 {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 30px auto 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "LeagueGothicRegular", "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond", "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond", "Impact", sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.conversation table {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  width:430px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.conversation th {
  padding: 9px 0 9px 11px;
  border-top: 1px solid {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
  text-align:right;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:1.2;
}
.conversation td {
  padding: 9px;
  border-top: 1px solid {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1.2;
}
.conversation tr:first-child td,
.conversation tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0;
}
.link h2 a {
  color: {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:24px;
  font-family:"LeagueGothicRegular",
  "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",
  "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond",
  "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond",
  "Impact",
  sans-serif;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  background: {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  display:block;
  padding:5px 0 5px;
  margin:30px auto 22px;
  width:430px;
}
.link h2 a span {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid {
    color: Background
  }
  ;
  border-left:0;
  border-right:0;
}
.link .body {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.answer {
  width: 465px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.answer-question .body {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  padding:10px 16px;
  width:318px;
  float:left;
  line-height:1.4;
}
.answer-asker {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
}
.answer-point {
  width: .7em;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
.answer-point-top,
.answer-point-bottom {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.answer-point-top {
  border-bottom: 8px solid {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  border-right:8px solid rgba(0,
  0,
  0,
  0);
}
.answer-point-bottom {
  border-left: 8px solid {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  border-bottom:8px solid rgba(0,
  0,
  0,
  0);
}
.answer-asker .answer-asker-avatar {
  float: right;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
}
.answer-asker .answer-asker-avatar a {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.answer-answer {
  margin-top: 22px;
}
.answer-label {
  width: 35px;
  float: left;
  color: {
    color: Accent
  }
  ;
  font-family:"LeagueGothicRegular",
  "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold",
  "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond",
  "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond",
  "Impact",
  sans-serif;
  font-size:48px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.answer-answer .body {
  margin-left: 35px;
}
.body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.body em {
  font-style: italic;
}
.body strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.body p,
.body blockquote {
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
}
.body p {
  text-indent: 1em;
}
.body ul+p,
.body ol+p,
.body blockquote+p,
.body p:first-of-type {
  text-indent: 0;
}
.body ul,
.body ol {
  margin: .75em 2em;
}
.body li {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: .35em 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
.body ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.body ul li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
.body ol ol,
.body ul ul {
  margin: .75em 2em;
}
.body li ol li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
.body li ul li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
.body blockquote {
  padding: 0 .85em 0 .85em;
  margin: .75em 1.15em;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
  font-style: italic;
}
.post-notes {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}
.post-notes li {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
  padding: 6px 5px 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.post-notes .avatar {
  display: none;
}
.post-notes blockquote {
  padding: 0 1em 0 .45em;
  margin: 7px 6px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
}
.post-notes blockquote a {
  color: {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
}
#disqus_thread {
  width: 430px;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
}
#footer {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#navigation {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, .5);
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 16px 0;
}
#navigation-left,
#navigation-right {
  width: 129px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#navigation-left {
  float: left;
}
#navigation-right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
#navigation-center {
  width: 243px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#navigation-center input {
  border: 1px solid {
    color: Links
  }
  ;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:transparent;
  height:23px;
  line-height:23px;
  color: {
    color: Text
  }
  ;
  font-size:14px;
  width:231px;
  padding:0 5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  font-family:Baskerville,
  “Times New Roman”,
  Times,
  serif;
}
#navigation-center #search-background {
  background: {
    color: Links
  }
  ;
  opacity:.5;
  height:25px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
#credit {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
</style> <style type="text/css"> {
  CustomCSS
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>{Title}{block:PostSummary} &bull; {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}</title>
 {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}
  <meta name="color:Background" content="#96E4EF" />
  <meta name="color:Text" content="#736653" />
  <meta name="color:Links" content="#FFFFFF" />
  <meta name="color:Accent" content="#FFFFFF" />
  <meta name="if:Show RSS Link" content="1" />
  <meta name="if:Show Archive Link" content="1" />
  <meta name="if:Show Likes Link" content="1" />
  <meta name="if:Show Notes" content="1" />
  <meta name="if:White Audio Player" content="1" />
  <meta name="text:Disqus Shortname" content="" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/usaykzx/4P5ky45bz/jquery.example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="container">
  
  <div id="header">
   
   <ul>
    {block:IfShowRSSLink}<li><a href="{RSS}">{lang:RSS}</a></li>{/block:IfShowRSSLink}
    {block:IfShowArchiveLink}<li><a href="/archive">{lang:Archive}</a></li>{/block:IfShowArchiveLink}
    {block:IfShowLikesLink}<li><a href="http://www.tumblr.com/liked/by/{Name}">{lang:Likes}</a></li>{/block:IfShowLikesLink}
    {block:HasPages} 
      {block:Pages}
        <li><a href="{URL}">{Label}</a></li>
      {/block:Pages}
    {/block:HasPages}
   </ul>
    
   <h1><a href="/">{Title}</a></h1>
   
   {block:Description}
     <p>{Description}</p>
   {/block:Description}
   
   <div id="submit_asks">
   {block:SubmissionsEnabled}<li><a href="/submit">{SubmitLabel}</a></li>{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
   {block:AskEnabled}<li><a href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a></li>{/block:AskEnabled}
   </div>
    
  </div>
  
  {block:Posts}
  <div class="post">
  
    <hr />
  
    <div class="post-meta">
      <a href="{Permalink}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}</a>
      {block:IfShowNotes}
        {block:NoteCount}
          &bull; <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
        {/block:NoteCount} 
      {/block:IfShowNotes}
      {block:IfDisqusShortname}
        &bull; <a class="dsq-comment-count" href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread">{lang:Comments}</a>
       {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
       
       {block:ContentSource}
           &bull; <a href="{SourceURL}" style="max-width:300px; text-overflow:clip;">{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{WhiteLogoURL}" width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" style="vertical-align:top;" />{/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceTitle}{/block:NoSourceLogo}</a>
       {/block:ContentSource}
       
    </div>
    
    <div class="post-content">
    
      {block:Photo}
        <div class="photo{block:Caption} captioned{/block:Caption}">
         
          <div class="photo-wrapper">{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}</div>
          
          {block:Caption}
            <div class="body">
              {Caption}
            </div>
          {/block:Caption}
          
          <div class="clear"></div>
        
        </div>
      {/block:Photo}
      
      {block:Quote}
        <div class="quote">
      
          <div class="q-wrapper"><q class="{Length}">{Quote}</q></div>
          
          {block:Source}
          <div class="body">
            {Source}
          </div>
            {/block:Source}
          
        </div>
      {/block:Quote}
      
      {block:Text}
        <div class="text">
      
          {block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
        
          <div class="body">
            {Body}
            </div>
        
        </div> 
      {/block:Text}
      
      {block:Video}
        <div class="video{block:Caption} captioned{/block:Caption}">
       
          <div class="video-wrapper">{Video-500}</div>
          
          {block:Caption}
          <div class="body">
            {Caption}
          </div>
          {/block:Caption}
          
          <div class="clear"></div>
        
        </div>
      {/block:Video}
      
      {block:Audio}
        <div class="audio">
          
          <div class="audio-info {block:AlbumArt}hasart{/block:AlbumArt}">
            {block:AlbumArt}
              <div class="audio-info-left">
                <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" />
              </div>
            {/block:AlbumArt}
            <div class="audio-info-right {block:TrackName}hasmeta{/block:TrackName} {block:Artist}hasmeta{/block:Artist} {block:Album}hasmeta{/block:Album}">
              {block:TrackName}<div class="audio-trackname">{TrackName}</div>{/block:TrackName}
              {block:Artist}<div class="audio-artist">{Artist}</div>{/block:Artist}
              {block:Album}<div class="audio-album">{Album}</div>{/block:Album}
              {block:ifWhiteAudioPlayer}
                  <div class="audio-player">{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>
                {/block:ifWhiteAudioPlayer}
                {block:ifNotWhiteAudioPlayer}
                  <div class="audio-player">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
                {/block:ifNotWhiteAudioPlayer}
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          
          {block:Caption}
            <div class="body">
              {Caption}
            </div>
          {/block:Caption}
          
        </div>
      {/block:Audio}
      
      {block:Chat}
        <div class="conversation">  
        
           {block:Title}<h2>{Title}</h2>{/block:Title}
                       
            <table cellspacing="0">
              {block:Lines}
                <tr class="user{UserNumber}">
                  <th>{block:Label}{Label}{/block:Label}</th>
                  <td>{Line}</td>
                </tr>
              {/block:Lines}
            </table>
            
          </div> 
        {/block:Chat}
        
        {block:Link}
          <div class="link">
      
          <h2><a href="{URL}" {Target}><span>{Name}</span></a></h2>
          
          {block:Description} 
            <div class="body">
              {Description}
            </div>
          {/block:Description}
        
        </div>
        {/block:Link}
        
        {block:Answer}          
        <div class="answer">
        
          <div class="answer-question">
            <div class="answer-label">Q</div>
            <div class="body">
              {Question}
            </div>
            <div class="answer-asker post-{PostID}">
              <div class="answer-point">
                <div class="answer-point-top"></div>
                  <div class="answer-point-bottom"></div>
                </div>
                <style>
                  .post-{PostID} .answer-asker-avatar { background: url({AskerPortraitURL-64})}
                </style>
              <div class="answer-asker-avatar">{Asker}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="answer-answer">
             <div class="answer-label">A</div>
            <div class="body">
              {Answer}
            </div>
          </div>
        
        </div>
        {/block:Answer}
    
    </div>
    
    {block:IfShowNotes}
      {block:PostNotes} 
        <div class="post-notes">
          {PostNotes}
        </div>
      {/block:PostNotes} 
    {/block:IfShowNotes}
    
    {block:PermalinkPage}
        {block:IfDisqusShortname}
          {block:Permalink}
          <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/embed.js"></script>
          <noscript><a href="http://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">{lang:View the discussion thread}</a></noscript>
          {/block:Permalink}
        {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
      {/block:PermalinkPage}
  
  </div>
  {/block:Posts}
  
  <div id="footer">
    
    <div id="navigation">
      
      {block:NextPage}<div id="navigation-left"><a href="{NextPage}">{lang:Older}</a></div>{/block:NextPage}
      {block:PreviousPage}<div id="navigation-right"><a href="{PreviousPage}">{lang:Newer}</a></div>{/block:PreviousPage}

        <div id="search-background"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="credit">
      <span>Designed by <a href="http://sleepoversf.tumblr.com/">Sleepover</a></span>
    </div>
  
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.prefill').example(function() {
     return $(this).attr('title'); 
    });
  });
  </script>
  
  {block:IfDisqusShortname}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var query = '?';
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
            query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
        }
        }
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
    })();
    //]]>
    </script>
  {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML around the Submit button in invalid, you have `<li>` tags that aren't in a corresponding `<ul>`. Make sure your HTML is correct and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Whoops, missed that completely, but still no good.

Comment: It's being added in this line: `<a href="{Permalink}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}</a>`, so the date is not coming through, but the comma is.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not either. This code seems to format two different pages at the same time, and there doesn't seem to be any place where a comma is added that when removed solves the problem. This is quite odd..

Comment: Even though I haven't found a solution, I really appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open F12 Developer tools in your browser, you will find a button that looks like a cursor clicking an element. This allows you to hover over elements, and when you click them it shows you where in the markup it is located. 
When searching yours, I found it to be in a div with the class "post-meta". I would suggest deleting the content of this, which is simply an anchor that doesn't link to anything with a comma in it. 
You can see [here](http://oi67.tinypic.com/9qe9hc.jpg) (screenshot of my browser).

Comment: Okay, yes that does get rid of the comma, but it also removes the date formatting on the main page. This is how it's supposed to look:[http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Sd3.jpg].        This is how removing "post-meta" makes it look: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/OoIrP.jpg]

Comment: In that case, try just removing the comma from the link, not the link itself.

Comment: From this link? <a href="{Permalink}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year}</a>

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure which link you're referring to. That's the only link within the class that contains a comma

Comment: If you look at the screenshot I linked to, you can see in the developer tools on the right side that a link is highlighted in blue. That is what is causing the comma. Either remove the link from there or just remove the comma. If you just remove the comma, the link still might make a gap in the page. This link contains no dynamic content such as dates, it simply is an empty link with a comma in it. (Notice this is a different thread to the one that bought up the date link.)

Comment: Okay, I see what your talking about when using the web inspector, but when I'm editing the code on Tumblr, this is all I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgIL.png

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, go to customise and scroll down to advanced. In the area where you can add custom css, try setting post-meta to display: none;

Comment: That's solved it! Man, thanks for putting up with me. Web design is definitely not my forte lol. The help was much appreciated!